# What makes the following Docker layer to invalidate cache in Kaniko?

Tags: docker, kaniko

I have a two stages build using Docker, in the second stage of build I have something like this:

```yaml
ARG COMPOSER_VERSION=2.5
ARG PHP_VERSION=7.4-apache
FROM --platform=${TARGETPLATFORM} php:${PHP_VERSION} AS composer

COPY --from=composer:2.5 /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN apt-get -yq update && \
    apt-get -yqq install ssh git zlib1g-dev libzip-dev zip unzip && \
    docker-php-ext-install zip && \
    mkdir -p -m 0600 /root/.ssh && \
    ssh-keyscan eae-git.eng.utah.edu >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

COPY ./html .

ARG CACHE_BUST_COMPOSER

RUN COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer install --prefer-dist --no-scripts --no-progress --no-interaction --no-dev -vvv --ignore-platform-req=ext-bcmath --ignore-platform-req=ext-gd --ignore-platform-req=ext-zip --ignore-platform-req=ext-ldap --ignore-platform-req=ext-exif --ignore-platform-req=ext-imagick --ignore-platform-req=ext-mongodb

FROM --platform=${TARGETPLATFORM} php:${PHP_VERSION} AS build

COPY --from=composer:2.5 /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer

RUN apt-get update && \
    mkdir -p /var/run/slapd && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -yqq -f --no-install-recommends \
    git \
    supervisor \
    vim \
    slapd \
    ldap-utils \
    ldapscripts \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libgmp-dev \
    libldb-dev \
    libldap2-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    imagemagick \
    libmagickwand-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libmongoc-dev \
    libbson-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    libcap2-bin \
    zlib1g-dev \
    ghostscript \
    && docker-php-ext-configure bcmath \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg --with-webp \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gmp \
    && docker-php-ext-configure intl \
    && docker-php-ext-configure ldap \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-configure exif \
    && docker-php-ext-configure xmlrpc \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) bcmath gd gmp intl ldap pdo_mysql exif xmlrpc zip \
    && pecl install imagick mongodb \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick mongodb \
    && apt-get purge --auto-remove -y $PHPIZE_DEPS \
    && apt-get clean autoclean \
    && apt-get autoremove --yes \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && rm -rf /usr/src \
    && a2enmod vhost_alias \
    && a2enmod rewrite headers \
    && setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/sbin/apache2

COPY --from=composer --chown=www-data /var/www/html /var/www/html

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN php artisan storage:link \
    && php artisan vendor:publish --all --no-interaction \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www \
    && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/log/apache2 \
    && find /var/www/html -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \; \
    && find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;

COPY ./build/docker/apache /etc/apache2/

ARG ENV

RUN if [ "$ENV" = "DEV" ] ; then \
        mv /etc/apache2/dev.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf ; \
        rm /etc/apache2/prod.conf ; \
    else \
        mv /etc/apache2/prod.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf ; \
        rm /etc/apache2/dev.conf ; \
    fi

ADD ./build/docker/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf

ADD ./build/docker/php.ini-production "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

USER www-data

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]
```

Using GitLab CI to run the Kaniko:

```yaml
Build a New Image:
  stage: build
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:v1.18.0-debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - CACHE_BUST_COMPOSER=$(date +%s)
    - /kaniko/executor
      --cache=true
      --cache-repo="${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/cache"
      --snapshot-mode=redo
      --use-new-run
      --skip-unused-stages
      --context "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}"
      --dockerfile "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/build/docker/Dockerfile"
      --destination "${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}${DIR}:${LATEST_VERSION}"
      --build-arg EAE_GITLAB_TOKEN=${EAE_GITLAB_TOKEN}
      --build-arg CACHE_BUST_COMPOSER=${CACHE_BUST_COMPOSER}
      --build-arg ENV=PROD
```

When I'm using Docker on my local machine it caches this layer no problem but when I run the same build using Kaniko it always says it cannot find the cache layer for this one.

A little bit of more context, the first layer is composer install layer and it always going to be invalidated as it is required for our build and also cache repo for Kaniko is working just fine, it finds some layers and use them but not all of them.

Does any have any idea what I'm missing here? this layer is big one and takes a lot of time to build.

Comment: Can you post your entire Dockerfile ? And your command when you built with kaniko?

Comment: @BorisBRESCIANI Updated my Dockerfile and added Kaniko command I'm runing using GitLab CI